# Text-to-Speech speaks in the incorrect language at iOS

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech

Here is the problem.
I need the text-to-speech function for the French language at my website.

Here is the code that I use.

Using the https://responsivevoice.org/ API:

```
responsiveVoice.setDefaultVoice("French Female");
responsiveVoice.speak(text);
```

Using the built-in SpeechSynthesisUtterance:

```
let msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
msg.text = text;
msg.volume = 1;
msg.rate = 1;
msg.pitch = 1;
msg.lang = 'fr-FR';
msg.voice = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices()[9];
window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
```

It works correctly in Google Chrome on the Windows laptop and in Opera on iOS.

But neither of them works correctly in Google Chrome and Safari browsers at my iPhone.
It speaks in English instead of French.

Previously, it worked correctly and I didn't change anything about it.
I don't know for sure but it seems that this problem starts happening after the recent iOS update.
Maybe it tries to speak in my default language instead of the chosen one. But I don't know how to fix it.

Any help is appreciated!

**UPD**
There is indeed some bug with default language.
I've changed the language of my iPhone to French and it starts speaking French.
But I still don't know how to make it speak the language I want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the exact issue. It works perfectly on Desktop but on iPhone the iOS read German texts in English.

Answer (score 0):

```
msg.voice = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices()[9];
```

The number and order of voices is different per browser / OS, so asking for voice 9 will give different results.

It may be that if the msg.voice and msg.lang don't match the default voice is used instead e.g. if you set the lang to fr-FR but the selected voice's lang attribute is es-ES.

To test this out try:

```
msg.voice = speechSynthesis.getVoices().find(voice => /fr(-|_)FR/.test(voice.lang));
```

This will select the first French/French voice it finds.

It's necessary to use the (-|_) part because some browsers use dash and others an underscore.

(It's not necessary to type window before speechSynthesis. Also I suggest that you comment out the volume, rate and pitch lines until you get it to work.)